# jQuery settimeout and show

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, settimeout

Sorry for this rookie question, I am trying to make the three red speech bubbles appear one by one, please see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/FLt9Z/

That section of javascript looks like this:

```
function leftappear() {
    $('#redbubble-left').show();
}

function topappear() {
    $('#redbubble-top').show();
}

function rightappear() {
    $('#redbubble-right').show();
}


var animation_script = [
    {
         at_time: 30 * 1000, // 30 seconds
         animation: leftappear()
    },
    {
         at_time: 31 * 1000, // 31 seconds
         animation: topappear()
    },
    {
         at_time: 32 * 1000, // 32 seconds
         animation: rightappear()
    }
];

var current_time = 0;

function animate_next() {
    var next = animation_script.shift(),
        time_between = next.at_time - current_time;
    setTimeout(function () {
        current_time = next.at_time;
        next.animation();
        animate_next();
    }, time_between);
}
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Nice graphics, but your message is missing a question. Don't let us guess the question or it might get closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You were CALLING the animation methods instead of REFERENCING them in your animation_script
2. you were never triggering the FIRST animate next.

http://jsfiddle.net/FLt9Z/1/

Here are the two major changes.

```
var animation_script = [
    {
         at_time: 2* 1000, // 30 seconds
         animation: leftappear // NOTE: drop the parens ()
    },
    {
         at_time: 3* 1000, // 31 seconds
         animation: topappear // NOTE: drop the parens ()
    },
    {
         at_time: 4* 1000, // 32 seconds
         animation: rightappear // NOTE: drop the parens ()
    }
];
```

and then 2, kicking it off, I simply added `animate_next();` to the bottom.  You can put this in your init script at the top or somewhere else.  This was just for demo purposes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the first answer I'd also like to point out your current code keeps on calling itself even though its gone through the list of bubbles to show, instead I would just loop through it once and set the timeouts:

```
$.each(animation_script, function(i, animation) {
    var next = animation_script.shift(),
        time_between = next.at_time - current_time;
    setTimeout(function() {
        current_time = next.at_time;
        next.animation();
    }, time_between);
});
```

Comment: I think I get the logic. Thanks :)